# Incorrect velocity in range doppler map

Tags: fft, matlab, doppler

I am trying to simulate tx, rx and if signals and from the if signal, compute the range and doppler of the target. In the function below, when i generate the range doppler heatmap, i am getting range values correctly in the plot but velocity always remains zero. Can anyone help me with why this is happening? I am considering three targets. Number of samples is 64 and number of chirps is 64. IFADCOuptut is 3 by 64 by 64

Code :

```
for targetIdx = 1:tgtNum

    IFADCOutput_target = squeeze(IFADCOutput(targetIdx,:, :));
    rangeDopplerMatrix = fft2(IFADCOutput_target .* windowTensor, pulseNum, numChirpSamples);
    rangeDopplerMatrixShifted = fftshift(rangeDopplerMatrix);
    rangeDopplerMatrices(targetIdx,:,:) = rangeDopplerMatrixShifted;
    rangeDopplerMatrixAbs = abs(rangeDopplerMatrixShifted);
    
    %plot
    figure;
    dataLen=round(length(IFADCOutput(1,1,:))/2);
    rangeData = ((-dataLen:(dataLen-1))/(2*dataLen))*fsIF*physconst('LightSpeed')/(2*rdrH.signalParams.chirpRate);
    velocityData = ((-dataLen:(dataLen-1))/(2*dataLen))*rdrH.generalParams.lambda / (4 * timePri);
    surf(rangeData, velocityData,rangeDopplerMatrixAbs,'EdgeColor','none');
    view(2);
    title(sprintf('2D fft adc plot - Target at 1m'));
    ylabel('Velocity');
    xlabel('Range (m)');
    xlim([rangeData(1), rangeData(end)]);
    ylim([velocityData(1), velocityData(end)]);
    
end
```

Output : (range is 1, velocity  is 1)

[image]

Comment: Can you show where IFADCOutput comes from?  If there's no pulse-to-pulse variation, or if the data is all real you're likely going to just see a peak at DC.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m1mezgwTSFk2hv0CTXJqpbpCmL4_xb3J?usp=sharing - i have added the complete code here